# How to set up clustered R environment variables?

Tags: r, environment-variables

I want to set up several groups of variables when starting an R session.

I know I can store my environment variables in a .Renviron file, but I don't know how to add groups.

I hope I can use this kind of formatted .Renviron file:

```
[group1]
a = 1
b = 2
[group2]
a = 2
b = 1
```

to get environment variables in R like:

```
> group1$a
> 1
```

Is this possible? Is there any better ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the configr, config and startup packages on CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lists:

```
l1 <- list()
l1$a <- 1
l1$b <- 2

l2 <- list(a = 2, b = 1)

> l2$a
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid that this is not what I want. I cannot use your answer to set up variables when starting an R session. I want to use .Renviron file instead of creating variables by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code you could put in a file that is accessed at startup automatically and silently:

```
group1 <- new.env()
 group1$a = 1
 group1$b = 2
group2 <- new.env()
  group2$a = 2
  group2b = 1
```

To see your options you can refer to the `?Startup` help page. The .Renviron option is mentioned there. My preference is to use a ".Rprofile" to hold R code in a working directory. That way I can have multiple working project "environments". If you are using Rstudio, you may need to instead read its documentation about the startup process it uses.

There is going to be some ambiguity in discussions using the term "environment variables" since the usual terminology is to call "group1" and group2" simply "environments", while the term "environment variables" is typically used to refer to system "environment variables" (accessible with `Sys.getenv()`.)